# Display results by the hour in Access

Tags: ms-access

Have a database that contains call information for an emergency call center.  Need to develop a report that visually graphs out the average number of calls by the hour for any given month.  The only applications I have available to me are Access and Excel to do this with.

I have the data easily available in the format "MM/DD/YY HH:MM:SS"  When I export this to Excel it retains that format.  My issue is that I need to sort all of the calls that came in between 0000 and 0059:59 together.  Any ideas how I can do that?  (well over 10k records per month, so individually removing the dates is going to be a pain in the neck)

Comment: What have you tried? I suggest you Pivot Tables so you can group your data by days aand then filter by hours. Also, try to extract the hour part to a new column so you can filter by it

Comment: Once I got the data into excel I sorted by date and went down the column and subtracted the date for each record.  Took a few minutes, but it got me into a place where I had only the times in the field.  However, now excel is looking at those fields as plain text so I can't sort them or format cells appropriately.

Comment: Apparently I was really tired yesterday, because I was able to figure it out this morning.  The lesson here is when the boss asks if you want to work a little OT the answer should always be NO!

Comment: To extract only hour from a cell is really easy. Example: Let's say `A1 = 14/03/2018 15:21:43`. Then in B1 just type formula `=A1-INT(A1)`. Drag down and you will have all your hours in about 0.003 seconds.